# Node express, memory overflow on res.send

Tags: node.js, express, memory-management

So I have an express server that tries to send back a lot of JSON data (625,763,181 chars if stringified) with `res.send(data)`. This crashes the application with

`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory``

(more info can be found on my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56894660/best-steps-to-debug-a-javascript-heap-out-of-memory-error) on this topic)

Here's a few snapshots of the heap before and after it tries to send the data:

[image]

As you can see the memory goes from 28MB to 700MB and 97% of it is allocated as strings (and inspecting it I see that it's the JSON data stringified).

So my question is: Am I doing anything wrong here, should I compress the JSON somehow or use something other than `res.send`? or can I just not send that much data?

OBS: I know I can add `--max-old-space-size=8192` but I'm trying to host the project on a server with limited space that runs out with or without that flag.

EDIT: I'm leaving this up because there might be optimisations I hadn't thought of, and I'm really interested. But I found a bug in my data causing it to grow in O(n*m) instead of just O(n+m), reducing the size from 625,763,181 chars to 131,700 chars.

Comment: You read the JSON data from a file?

Comment: Nope it's built dynamically before being sent (sources collected from firestore server)